# Question about a line in the proof of Zorn's lemma in Jech.

Tags: set-theory

The proof of Zorn's lemma in Jech is the following

> *Proof*. We construct (using a choice function for nonempty sets of P), a chain in P that leads to a maximal element of P. We let, by induction, $a_\alpha =$ an element of P such that $a_\alpha > a_\beta$ for every $\beta < \alpha$ if there is one. **Clearly, if $\alpha > 0$ is a limit ordinal, then $C_\alpha = \{a_\beta : \beta < \alpha \}$ is a chain in P and $a_\alpha$ exists by the assumption.** Eventually, there is $\theta$ such that there is no $a_{\theta + 1} \in P$, $a_{\theta + 1} > a_\theta$. Thus $a_{\theta}$ is a maximal element of P.

I would like some clarification on the bolded section, as I fail to see why it's true. So let's take for instance $P = \{0, 1\}$. Then we can choose $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$. For the limit ordinal $\omega$, $C_\omega = \{a_\xi\ : \xi < \omega\} = \{0, 1\}$.  So then $a_\omega = ??$

Comment: In this case $\theta=1$: there is no $a_2$, let alone an $a_\omega$.

Comment: In your example there is no $a_2$, and $a_1$ is a maximal element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I think I get the proof. But the wording is bothering me here.  The sentence "If $\alpha > 0$ is a limit ordinal, then ..... ....., $a_\alpha$ exists by the assumption." Isn't that outright stating that $a_\alpha$ exists for every limit $\alpha >0$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Not quite. The sentence means: "If $\alpha>0$ is a limit ordinal, and $a_\beta$ exists for all $\beta<\alpha$, then ..." The existence of $a_\alpha$ is part of the conclusion.

Comment: @Andrés: You’re right: I read too fast.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo This is a bit semantically confusing for me, because when I read the sentence, I can see that conclusions are being reached on the fact that $\alpha>0$ is a limit ordinal alone.

Comment: If it helps, imagine that the proof is poorly written, more a hint than anything else, and your task is to actually find the right argument suggested by the hint. Trying to read the proof sentence by sentence may not be the best strategy.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you define an order embedding from an ordinal into $P$. Each time you take a point strictly above the previous ones. The result, if so, is a chain. And therefore it has an upper bound - by the assumption on $P$ - so we can choose one using our choice function.

Comment: If you take the bolded sentence literally, then $a_\alpha$ exists for *any* limit $\alpha$, which clearly isn't true. That was my initial confusion, but I get that $a_\alpha$ must exist for limit $\alpha$ if $a_\beta$ exists for all $\beta < \alpha$.

Comment: Maybe I'm just used to Jech's writing style, but the assumption that we got to the $\alpha$ stage seems to be implicitly embedded into that bolded part, and somewhat clear from context. But maybe I just read a lot of his books and got used to it.